# Calculating the Sum of Squared Deviations between two Normalized Price Series

Tags: equities, statistics, price, mean, normalization

How can I calculate the sum of square deviations between two normalized price series according to [(Gatev et. co 2006)](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/434/434Context/PairsTrading/PairsTradingGGR.pdf)? My normalized price series of stocks $X$ and $Y$ consist of the cumulative total daily (log) returns of adjusted close series for stock data taken from Yahoo Finance.

According to some research on the internet it seems I am to:

> Divide the time series of the share prices by the price on the first
>   day of the pairs identification period and then subtract the two new
>   time series from each other, square these differences and sum the
>   result. The smaller the value, the more likely the two stocks are to
>   be a good pair.

If that were the case, I would end up with the formula:

$$SSD=\sum(\frac{x_1,x_2,..,x_n}{x_1}-\frac{y_1,y_2,..,y_n}{y_1})^2$$
Where $X=(x_1,x_2,..x_n)$ and $Y=(y_1,y_2,..y_n)$ are stock price series.

But according to other research, sum of squared deviations refers simply to sum of squares, so then the formula is:
$$SS = \sum((x_1,x_2,..,x_n)-\frac{x_1+x_2+..+x_n}{n})^2,or\sum(X-\bar{X})^2$$
But how would I incorporate $Y$ into the second one? Subtract the two results so $SS(X)-SS(Y)$?

If anyone could shed some light on the issue, that'd be fantastic!

Thanks.

Comment: Try both methods. There is no correct answer.

Comment: Alright, I've chosen to go with the first equation according to a UBS Monograph. Thanks.

Comment: To refine what I said, the best method is the one that is best according to cross-validation. You only start having to worry about what is best a priori if you start fitting to your test set by trying too many approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing to mark this question "Answered" as @user2763361 has pointed out that there is no "correct" answer. I've chosen to go with the first equation according to a UBS Monograph. Thanks.